# Count battleship leetcode that doesn't output the same value after changing parameters

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

**Prompt:**
Given an 2D board, count how many battleships are in it. The battleships are represented with 'X's, empty slots are represented with '.'s. You may assume the following rules:

1. You receive a valid board, made of only battleships or empty slots.
2. Battleships can only be placed horizontally or vertically. In other words, they can only be made of the shape 1xN (1 row, N columns) or Nx1 (N rows, 1 column), where N can be of any size.
3. At least one horizontal or vertical cell separates between two battleships - there are no adjacent battleships.

**Example:**
    `count_bs([["X",".",".","X"],[".",".",".","X"],[".",".",".","X"]]) 
    returns 2`

```
[X, ., ., X]
[., ., ., X]
[., ., ., X]
```

**Solution:** This code is correct.

```
def count_bs(grid):

    rows, cols = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    count = 0 

    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            if ((grid[r][c] == '.') or (r > 0 and grid[r-1][c] == 'X') or (c > 0             and grid[r][c-1]) == 'X'):
                continue
            else:
                count += 1
    return count
```

I was messing around with the 2D array and changed the parameters to see if it's correct. **range(x-1) and in the conditions (r < len(grid) and grid[checks below instead of above)** However, I do not get the same answer. How are these two not identical?

```
def count_bs(grid):

    rows, cols = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    count = 0 

    for r in range(rows-1):
        for c in range(cols-1):
            if ((grid[r][c] == '.') or (r < rows and grid[r+1][c] == 'X') or (c < cols             and grid[r][c+1]) == 'X'):
                continue
            else:
                count += 1
    return count
```

So, the code above goes from top left to bottom right and checks the rows above and columns to the left to see if there are adjacent 'X' values. My code also goes from top left to bottom right, but checks the rows to the bottom and right.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading this, but won't `grid[r][c]` always return `True` given that `r` and `c` are in bounds? Both `.` and `X` evaluate to `True`.

Comment: @hoffee 
So, if there isn't an `X` it'll just trudge along. Similarly, if there is an `X` but there is also an adjacent `X` not in the place it should be, it'll trudge along.

Comment: @hoffee
I added an example to my post

Comment: So when checking for an `X` adjacent to position `grid[r][c]` (in the "correct" code), don't you need to check if `grid[r-1][c] == X`? The condition `grid[r-1][c]` by itself will not tell you if there is an `X` in that position.

Comment: @hoffee You are correct. I forgot to add those in this answer, but I did have it in my compiler. I'm still not getting the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a few small changes are needed to make your code work. You still need to loop over the entire range of `rows` and `cols`, but since you're looking at cells below and to the right of your current position, you need to change the conditions inside the loop. See here:

```
def count_bs(grid):

    rows, cols = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    count = 0 

    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            if ((grid[r][c] == '.') 
             or (r < rows-1 and grid[r+1][c] == 'X') 
             or (c < cols-1 and grid[r][c+1] == 'X')):
                continue
            else:
                count += 1
    return count
```

I only tried a few test cases but I believe this will work. As a side note, the original solution you gave is essentially counting the number of "top-left" corners of the ships, whereas your solution is counting the number of "bottom-right" corners (i.e., if we're at an `X` and there is not an `X` below us or to the right, then we must be at a bottom-right corner, so we increment the count). This might make the code a little more intuitive.